# sharing a common parameter in data fitting

Tags: matlab, parameters, curve-fitting, differential-equations, least-squares

I am trying to fit data to a non linear ODE system in order to estimate model parameters. I have data for three separate subjects as `data1,data2,data3`measured over the same time span. In estimating these parameters I want to keep one of the estimated parameters to be common among all subjects.

I have written the code similar to one at ['anlaysis.m' in here](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30869-fitting-with-matlab--statistics--optimization--and-curve-fitting).

But, still I am getting a different value for the parameter that I want to keep constant.

My code is something like:

```
thours = (1:100);

Y=[data1;data2;data3];

[fit,error]=lsqcurvefit(@model,initial,thours,Y,lb,ub,options)

function output= model(parameters,thours)

    x0=[10^5,0.01];

    a_1=parameters(1);%dependent on subject
    a_2=parameters(2);%dependent on subject
    a_3=parameters(3);%dependent on subject
    r1=parameters(4);%common to all subjects

    parameters1=[a_1,r1];
    parameters2=[a_2,r1];
    parameters3=[a_3,r1];

    [time,res1] = ode45(@(t,y)Equations(t,y,parameters1),thours,x0);
    [time,res2] = ode45(@(t,y)Equations(t,y,parameters2),thours,x0);
    [time,res3] = ode45(@(t,y)Equations(t,y,parameters3),thours,x0);

    function s=Equations(t,y,eval)
    s=zeros(2,1);
    % b, k are know  constant parameter values. The parameter estimated as
    % eval(2) should be constant among all subjects
    s(1)=(eval(2)*y(1))-eval(1)*y(2)*y(1);
    s(2)=b*(k-y(2))*y(1)-eval(1)*y(2);

    end

pred1=res1(:,1);

pred2=res2(:,1);
pred3=res3(:,1);

output=[pred1;pred2;pred3];

end
```

Can someone please explain to me how I can correct the code to evaluate a common parameter?

Comment: you mean you want `data3=4` for example?

Comment: @AnderBiguri There are 3 data sets and three fittings. But when fitting I want one of the parameters to be estimated commonly for all data sets. So the estimated value for `r1` should be the same for all 3 subjects.

Comment: mm you may need to write `equations` as a coupled function for all 2 inputs.... no idea

Comment: When I have done this in the past, I fit a single function where the non-common parameters in the function were evaluated depended on which data set was being evaluated during fitting. sort of "if data set 1 use parameter A else if data set 2 use parameter B else if data set 3 use parameter C" and use the common r1 in every case. Note that this weights the fit toward the data set with the most data points, if that is problematic you will need to weight by the number of data points in each data set.

Comment: @JamesPhillips So, where should I add the `if `condition? Is it when I call ode45 or is it with `lsqcurvefit` function? In here am I not doing a similar thing?

Comment: I do not use the MATrix LABoratory and was speaking conceptually.